# Having trouble connecting to Github with Brew

Tags: github, sass, bower, bower-install

I'm having some trouble trying to connect to my teams GitHub to download correlated sass files using bower. When trying to download through terminal I keep on receiving an error response 443 (see below)

```
bower ENOTFOUND     Request to https://registry.bower.io/packages/px-notification failed: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.bower.io registry.bower.io:443 GC02RQ27YG8WPE:scss
```

This is the response to doing a basic bower install from GitHub. At first, I believed it was a proxy error or firewall but I have tried connecting using tethering and outside firewall networks with the same result. As a note, the error did not occur yesterday using the same process so am lead to believe it might be a server issue.

- bower vr. 1.8.4 and GitHub status shows running fine.

If you have any ideas or solutions I could use the help. 
Thanks, everyone.